# Dependency on generated source set using Gradle Composite Builds and Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I build my project (call this project **B**) and some of its upstream dependency projects with Gradle **composite builds**. One of these upstream projects (call this project **A**) has an alternate source set configured to avoid producing warnings on generated code.

This is configured like:

```
sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDir "$buildDir/generated-sources/generated/main/java"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile sourceSets.generated.compileClasspath
    compile sourceSets.generated.output
}
compileGeneratedJava.options.warnings = false
jar { from sourceSets.generated.output }
```

This works fine building with gradle from the command line. But, in IntelliJ Idea, it imports the two source sets as separate modules: **A_main** and **A_generated**. It creates a dependency from **B_main** on **A_main**, but not on **A_generated**.

This results in run-time errors when running from IntelliJ IDEA. (B does not directly use any generated classes from A).

How can this be resolved?

The versions I'm using are:

**IntelliJ IDEA:** 2017.2.5

**Gradle:** 4.2.1

Comment: I found that disabling the setting **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Gradle** -> **Create separate module per source set** works around this problem.

Comment: that however will change your dependency scope from 'compile' to 'provided', hence if your intellij build is not delegated to gradle, you won't be able to compile the project

Comment: This configuration is not adding the classes in JAR file. Is there any other configuration as well?